# How to disable markup option on images in NSTextView?

Tags: macos, swift, nstextview

I have an NSTextView, which has graphics enabled so that users can drag images into it. The problem is that it has an arrow on the image, which opens a dropdown menu. Is there a way to disable this menu, because it causes problems within my app.

Answer (score 0):

How about NSTextView's [`allowsImageEditing` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextView/allowsImageEditing)?

Set it to "`false`".

Comment: I know this is an old questions, but I ran into this today. I did set `allowsImageEditing = false` and the system Markup menu still shows.